# Move semantics and const references

Tags: c++, c++11

I've spend quite some time on implementing move semantics for my class but now I'm dealing with functions that use it.

Ok, so I have this object which has a lot of data on the heap: `CLargeOb` for which I implemented the move semantics (constructor and operator =). It is ideally used like this:

```
void OtherOb::Func(CLargeOb&& largeOb1, CLargeOb&& largeOb2)
{
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb1); // use objects
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb2); 
    m_largeOb1 = (CLargeOb&&)largeOb1; // save as members and trash the originals
    m_largeOb2 = (CLargeOb&&)largeOb2;
}
```

However it's not always possible to allow the objects to be moved/trashed, so I added these two functions:

```
void OtherOb::Func(const CLargeOb& largeOb1, CLargeOb&& largeOb2)
{
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb1);
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb2); 
    m_largeOb1 = largeOb1;
    m_largeOb2 = (CLargeOb&&)largeOb2;
}

void OtherOb::Func(CLargeOb&& largeOb1, const CLargeOb& largeOb2)
{
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb1);
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb2); 
    m_largeOb1 = (CLargeOb&&)largeOb1;
    m_largeOb2 = largeOb2;
}
```

Although it works, you can already guess it will become a major pain in the *ss when I have a function which takes 3 or more of these objects as parameters... Isn't there a clever way to solve this using templates or maybe 'perfect forwarding'?

Comment: @MooingDuck: works fine in VS2010, no problem. To invoke the operator =(&&) you must call it explicitly using std::move or the && cast. But the solution provided below it much better of course.

Comment: @demorge: oh right, I completely forgot the rules change when it's named.  Sorry for that

Comment: Please write `std::move(largeOb1)` instead of `(CLargeOb&&)largeOb1`. Generations of programmers to come will thank you for using the standard C++11 way of enabling a move instead of a non-idiomatic and borderline unreadable C/C++ mix.

Comment: Also, you may be interested in the following [FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/252000) on move semantics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As was the case in C++03, the guideline is: **if you want a copy, make it in the parameter list**.

This lets the caller deal with how you get the object, you just get an object regardless:

```
void OtherOb::Func(CLargeOb largeOb1, CLargeOb largeOb2) 
{ 
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb1); // use objects 
    SomeOtherFunc(largeOb2);  
    m_largeOb1 = std::move(largeOb1); // save as members and trash the originals 
    m_largeOb2 = std::move(largeOb2); // (you should use std::move, not cast)
}
```

The caller:

```
OtherOb o;

CLargeOb x, y;
const CLargeOb z;

o.Func(x, std::move(y)); // need x for later, done with y so move it
o.Func(std::move(x), z); // done with x, necessarily copy z
```

This is just as efficient as several specialized overloads. Why? *Because those already exist in the class as constructors*. Let the compiler figure out which to call at the call site for you, it already knows what to do.

Comment: Doesn't this move twice, instead of once? (NB: Of course, one additional move should be barely noticeable so I've upvoted anyway)

Comment: @Sjoerd: Yes, the hope is that the compiler will elide a move somewhere; and as you said even if it doesn't, it shouldn't matter.